# Probability for smallest and greatest

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have to deposit money five times. What is the probability that the first is the greatest and the last is the smallest ? ( five deposits are all different).

Answer : 1/20

I did total number of possibilities 5! for the denominator, but how do I get the chances for the numerator?

Comment: Keeping the largest and smallest away, how many ways to order the rest?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**Fix the smallest and the greatest, you have to permute the remaining $3$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it should be $\frac{1}{5}\times \frac{1}{4}$ because there is a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of the first deposit being the greatest, and then since there are $4$ deposits left, there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of the last deposit being the smallest.